# regex to match some string

Tags: regex, splunk

I am working a project that need to match certain string in the output..

here the sample:

```
user code   timestamp                   Action Name                 S#TPLC Field Name  User code group profile              
SNGLASK     2012-05-30-20.33.53.003000  Insert User                 I                  TEST5       DISPLAY
SNGLASK     2012-05-23-22.06.44.422000  Change Password RSO part    U     LERAPR      SNGCHIS     FULL_AUTH
SNGLASK     2012-05-30-20.34.39.066000  Insert User Group Profil    I                             *NONE
```

basically i have a application that need to understand that each row after the space is belong to next column.
Then, after action name everything can be treated as other.
hence, i have come out a regex format like below:

```
REGEX = ^([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)s(.*)$
FORMAT = userCode::"$1" TimeStamp::"$2" ActionName::"$3" Others::"$4"
```

The strategy is recognize the string then ignore the space after that. However, this thing work until action name as they might be space between the action name.
Hence, my problem is, how to use regex to let it recognize the string within the action name like i need "insert user" as an input & "change password RSO part" as another input.

Comment: is this perl? whatever your language, better add the appropriate language tag to your question.

Comment: hi thanks for the inform, is not perl.. is a configuration file in one of application called splunk.
however, my problem is how to use regex to understand few string (with space) as an input

Answer (score 1):

Do multipart words like this:

```
((\S+\s)+)
```

which says one or more word, separated with one space.
so the regex whould be:

```
^((\S+\s)+)\s+(\S+)\s+((\S+\s)+)\s+(.*)$
```

Comment: Thanks!! it work..
However, i made some changes on the code
^([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+((\S+\s)+)\s+(.*)$

as i only need the 1 space for action name other still the same..
anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @Sahand Mozaffari, Sorry to trouble you again. after i try to implement you code i discovered still has a bit of mismatch. kindly refer to my source data to understand the follow problem :) REGEX = ^([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+((\S+\s)+)\s+(.*)$ FORMAT = userCode::"$1" TimeStamp::"$2" ActionName::"$3" Others::"$4" After apply the regex, the "Others" recognize --user and part as the data where it suppose to read I (space..) TEST5 as the data.. would you able to assist me on this? thanks

Comment: That is because (\S+\s) is your fourth group now. To not let this parentheses count as another group do this: (?>\S+\s) which means this parentheses is a non-capturing parentheses and is used just for grouping purpose.

Comment: You also could use named capturing groups to clarify your pattern and prevent such mistakes. the syntax for named-capturing groups is
(?<name>X)
_But be aware that not all flavors of regex support this_, and I'm not sure if yours does. check it.